# Output MySQL variables in PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have MySQL variables, which are echoing but I want to use them in an array and randomly display the results - it's for a competition - the random is working great but I can't get the variable to show correctly when they're in the array().

I have written the following:

```
<?php
    $answer = array('$this->item->correct_answer','$this->item->false_answer1','$this->item->false_answer2');
    shuffle($answer);
?>

<ol class="answers">
    <?php
        for( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
            echo "<li>$answer[$i]</li>";
    ?>  
</ol>
```

This is only outputting:

$this->item->correct_answer

$this->item->false_answer2

$this->item->false_answer1

Comment: you are treating $this->item->correct_answer as a string.. but that is not string... its output can be string/float/int as per db values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you've got `'` for the array inputs. That means you're setting a string. Revise it to:

```
$answer = array($this->item->correct_answer,$this->item->false_answer1,$this->item->false_answer2);
```

As demonstrated [On codepad.org](http://codepad.org/GB11WkrW)

Comment: @RustyIngles Anytime!:) Please mark it as the correct answer if you're done.